# How to aggregate two tables on a comma-separated string field?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, group-concat

In one table I have a column with multiple values separated by a comma. In the second, columns with `id` and `name`. I need to get names separated by a slash.

Table1:

| id | value1 | ids | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | 1,2,3 | efgh |
| 2 | ijkl | 1,4,6 | mnop |

Table2:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1AB |
| 2 | 2CD |
| 3 | 3EF |
| 4 | 4GH |
| 5 | 5IJ |
| 6 | 6KL |

```
SELECT
    a.*,  
    GROUP_CONCAT(b.name,'/') groupedName
FROM
    table1 a
LEFT JOIN
    table2 b ON b.id IN (a.ids)
WHERE
    a.id = 1
```

Result:

| id | value1 | ids | value2 | groupedName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abcd | 1,2,3 | efgh | 1AB/2CD/3EF |

Answer (score 1):

Given that your "*Table1.ids*" has `VARCHAR(n)` type, you can use the `LIKE` function for the matching condition on the `JOIN` between the two tables, only then apply the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregation function:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       t1.value1,
       t1.ids,
       t1.value2,
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name, '/') AS groupedName 
FROM       table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.ids LIKE t2.id || ',%'
        OR t1.ids LIKE  '%,' || t2.id || ',%'
        OR t1.ids LIKE           '%,' || t2.id
        OR t1.ids = t2.ids
GROUP BY t1.id,
         t1.value1,
         t1.ids,
         t1.value2
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5APeSgW1So69KSQdKsfPyf/0).

Comment: Thank you.
Unfortunately, it does not work if the ids contains only two or one comma-separated value.

Comment: If it contains only one comma-separated value, you can impose the equality, as per update on the answer. With two comma separated values, this should work. @DanielTengler

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `id` is the primary key of `table1`, use the operator `LIKE` in the `ON` clause like this:

```
SELECT t1.*,  
       GROUP_CONCAT(t2.name, '/') groupedName
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN table2 t2 
ON ',' || t1.ids || ',' LIKE '%,' || t2.id || ',%'
GROUP BY t1.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=03f3a2097cf52fdb243e6e87019959da).